# Improvements for a template

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates, article

I wanted to recreate a page from a famous journal. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,atbegshi,scrpage2,libertine,multicol,blindtext,fullpage,lettrine}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
%\newcommand{\header}{
%}
%\AtBeginShipOut{}
%\AtBeginShipOutFirst{}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
%\renewcommand{\columnsep}{0cm}
\deftripstyle{my}[0pt][0pt]{}{}{}{\bf\textsf{\thepage}}{}{\sf DER SPIEGEL Nr. 36/1.9.2018}
\pagestyle{my}
\setcounter{page}{74}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node[white,fill=red,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=.7cm,below=.5cm] (a) at ($(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.north east)$) {\sf\textbf{Ausland}};
            \node[below=1 of a] (b) {\scalebox{3}{\tt\textbf{56 Tage}}};
        \node[text width=1.3\textwidth,align=center,below=.5 of b] {\textbf{USA} Eine Mutter und ihr sechsjähriger Sohn fliehen vor der Gewalt in Honduras nach Texas. Dort werden sie voneindander getrennt. Als sie nach zwei Monaten wieder zusammenfinden, sind sie nicht mehr die gleichen. \textit{Von Marian Blasberg, Katrin Kuntz und Christoph Scheuermann}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \lettrine{\textbf{\texttt{E}}}{}s ist ein Uhr nachts, als Levis Osorio Andino aus einem traumlosen Schlaf schreckt. eine Wärterin tritt an ihr Hochbrett im Prot-Isabel-Gefängnis und rüttelt sie am Arm. \flqq 494, steh auf\frqq, ruft sie. \flqq Es ist so weit.\frqq

        Schlaftrunken packt Levis ihre Tasche und taumelt durch das Neonlicht der Korridore. 56 Tage lang hat sie Samir nicht gesehen, ihren sechsjährigen Sohn, der wie kein anderes ihrer Kinder an ihr hängt. Anfang Juni hatten sie nach Wochen auf der Flucht den Rio Grande überquert. Dann rissen ihr texanische Grenzschützer das Kind aus dem Arm. Amerika machte in jenen Wochen Ernst mit einer neuen Null-Toleranz-Politik., die vorsah, illegal eingewanderte Familien zu trennen. Jetzt geht es darum, das Chaos aufzuräumen, das dabei entstanden ist. Das Letzte, was Levis von Samir gehört hat, war, dass er dieses Heim in Phoenix, in das man ihn geflogen hatte, nicht mehr verlassen wollte.

        \flqq Überraschung\frqq, flötet die Wärterin und schiebt Levis in einen fensterlosen Raum. \flqq Samir ist nur noch kurz auf der Toilette.\frqq Levis sinkt auf einen Stuhl. Sie zittert. Dann steht er plötzlich in der Tür, an der Hand eines Sozialarbeiters, das Haar geschoren, das freche Zahnlückenlächeln eingefroren.

        \flqq Samir, mein Liebling\frqq, stammelt Levis, \flqq wie geht es dir?\frqq

        \flqq Ich weiß nicht, wer du bist.\frqq

        Levis geht einen Schritt auf Samir zu, er weicht zurück. Sie versucht es ein zweites Mal, er tritt nach ihr.

        \flqq Samir\frqq, sagt sie. \flqq Ich liebe dich!\frqq

        \flqq Du bist nicht meine Mutter.\frqq

        So erzählt es Levis, als sie ein paar Stunden nach diesem Wiedersehen übermüdet vor einem Teller Reis sitzt. Levis, die vor 26 Jahren in der honduranischen Stadt El Provernir geboren wurde, ist eine hübschen, rundliche Frau mit mandelförmigen Augen. Sie versucht, Worte für etwas zu finden, das ihr wie ein Albtraum vorkommt. Immer wieder ringt sie mit den Tränen, während Samir an ihrer Seite in die Fantasiewelt eines Handyspiels abtaucht.

        Fragt man ihn, wie es ihm geht, blickt er kurz auf und sagt: \flqq Ich bin aus Stahl.\frqq

        Die Sonne schimmert auf den Cafeteria-Tischen der Basilica-Herberge, die von der katholischen Kirche im Rio Grande Valley betrieben wird. Ein Gefängnisbus hat Levis und Samir in der Nacht hier abgesetzt, am südlichen Rand der USA, nicht weit von der Stelle, an der vor zwei Monaten ihr Floß anlegte. Sie sind jetzt frei, aber sie wissen nicht, wohin. Im Oktober, sagt Levis, beginne ihr Asylverfahren, bis dahin schiebe man sie immerhin nicht ab.

        Diese Herberge, in der normalerweise Pilgergruppen absteigen, ist jetzt eine Durchgangsstation für viele jender rund 3000 Familien, die Amerika Ende Juli nach und nach wieder zusammenführt. Es ist ein Ort der Menschlichkeit in einem Land, das seinen Kompass verloren hat.

        In der Lobby teilen Nonnen Kleiderspenden aus. Sie helfen, Verwandte ausfindig zu machen, und besorgen Bustickets. Sie verbinden Levis zum ersten Mal seit Wochen wieder mit ihrem Anwalt, der ihr am Telefon verspricht, einen Unterschlupf zu finden, an dem die Wunden heilen können, die sein Land ihr zugefügt hat.

        Die USA waren lange zeit ein Staat, dessen Grenzen offener waren als anderswo.
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
            \begin{center}
%               \textbf{Bis heute befinden sich noch immer 500 Kinder in der Obhut der Regierung.}
                \parbox{.3\textwidth}{\flushleft \textbf{Bis heute befinden sich noch immer 500 Kinder in der Obhut der Regierung.}}
            \end{center}
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        \flqq Gebt mir eure Müden, eure Armen/Eure geknechteten Massen, die sich danach sehen, frei zu atmen\frqq, so steht es am Fuß der Freiheitsstatue. Es ist das Fundament, das unverrückbar schien, seit die Vereinigten Staaten 1776 durch die Nachfahren europäischer Einwanderer gegründet wurden.

        Der 45. Präsident ist nun dabei, eine Abrissbirne auf diesen Sockel loszulassen. In den Augen des ehemaligen Bauunternehmers Donald Trump sind Menschen wie Levis, die vor der gewalt und der Armut in Mittelamerika fliehen, vor allem Kriminelle. Drogendealer nennt er sie, Vergewaltiger oder \flqq bad hombres\frqq. Trump glaubt, es seien zu viele, und um sie aufzuhalten, versprach er seinen Wählern den Bau einer Grenzmauer.

        Die Null-Toleranz-Politik, die Trumps Justizminister Jeff Sessions im April ausrief, war so etwas wie ein erster, unsichtbarer Wall; eine Maßnahme zur Abschreckung, die weniger kostet als ein Bauwerk aus Beton. Tausende Eltern wurden von Mitte Mai an in Haft genommene, ihre Kinder verteilte man über das Land. Manche fanden sich in Heimen wieder, andere kamen bei Pflegeeltern unter oder in leer stehenden Walmart-Supermärkten.
    \end{multicols}
        \vfill\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Huge\copyright Spiegel, \\[1ex]
        \Large Nr. 36/1.9.2018
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: How can be the code improved, such that it is clear and (when possible) very short (of course the main text can be outsourced into an another document)?

Comment: You could use titlesec to define the styles for sections, subsections and so on. This would spare you from writing the lengthy code in the beginning. (I am wondering if there are copyright issues if you recreate an official format.)

Comment: @marmot: Yeah, ouf course, you're right! I did use the `titlesec` option like in the earlier question¹ here, too, but then removed 'cause I thought it would be unnecessary for just two pages to use this option. Official format? I just texed the original journal I've got here next to me or how did you mean that? And a big thank for you for that fast response, I really appreciate that! ¹ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448931/strange-behaviour-with-textwidth

Comment: @marmot: Don't worry, I know it was Zarko (it isn't bad, but I really didn't copy you – I think Zarko didn't know that) and thank you for all that support (of course I did upvote all your posts ;)) Thank you again!

Comment: @marmot: You're absolutely right – I had to copy sometimes with such people (because I still go to school and some people just literally take my work and replace in a pdf-program my name with their). If I did copy you I'm really sorry – I didn't see your answer at first, I read it after my post … sorry again.

Comment: No, you did not copy me. First of all, your answer is clearly independent, and second, this is all trivial, and I had no intention to answer this *unless* it would have been a more conceptual question of how to store these signals in `pic`s (say) and reuse them to plot arbitrary signal curves.

Comment: I wouldn't use Ti*k*Z just for that small header, more something like `\begin{center}\colorbox{red}{\quad \textcolor{white}{Ausland}\quad}\\[1cm]\Large 56 Tage\end{center}` as Ti*k*Z is rather heavy (on CPU usage) just for that minor thing. Also you shouldn't use `\tt` but either `\ttfamily` or `\texttt`. Also I'd use `microtype`, especially for narrow columns this is a good idea to improve the overall visual appearance.

Comment: Also `scrpage2` is considered obsolete and superseded by `scrlayer-scrpage`. And if you don't use `blindtext` don't load it.

Comment: @Skillmon: These are really good points! I loaded `blindtext` just if someone wants to insert some. Could you make a MWE?

Comment: I'm at it :) Just wait a few more minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is not a complete retouch but I've changed some things. Especially I've recreated your header without Ti*k*Z (because answering [tikz-pgf] questions without Ti*k*Z is what the cool kids do). I also swapped `fullpage` for `geometry`.

And I'd most likely create a command for all those `\flqq`-`\frqq` pairs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,libertine,multicol,lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot,head=15mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
\ifoot{\pagemark}
\ofoot{DER SPIEGEL Nr. 36/1.9.2018}
\setcounter{page}{74}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-2.95cm}
\begin{center}
  \colorbox{red}{\quad\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries Ausland\strut\quad}%
  \\[1.1cm]
  % I wouldn't use scalebox here but \LARGE or something like that
  \scalebox{3}{\ttfamily\bfseries 56 Tage}\\[7.5mm]
  \textbf{USA}
  Eine Mutter und ihr sechsjähriger Sohn fliehen vor der Gewalt in
  Honduras nach Texas. Dort werden sie voneindander getrennt. Als
  sie nach zwei Monaten wieder zusammenfinden, sind sie nicht mehr
  die gleichen. \textit{Von Marian Blasberg, Katrin Kuntz und
  Christoph Scheuermann}%
\end{center}
\vspace{-1mm}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \lettrine{\textbf{\texttt{E}}}{}s ist ein Uhr nachts, als Levis Osorio Andino
  aus einem traumlosen Schlaf schreckt. Eine Wärterin tritt an ihr Hochbrett im
  Prot-Isabel-Gefängnis und rüttelt sie am Arm. \flqq 494, steh auf\frqq, ruft
  sie. \flqq Es ist so weit.\frqq

  Schlaftrunken packt Levis ihre Tasche und taumelt durch das Neonlicht der
  Korridore. 56 Tage lang hat sie Samir nicht gesehen, ihren sechsjährigen Sohn,
  der wie kein anderes ihrer Kinder an ihr hängt. Anfang Juni hatten sie nach
  Wochen auf der Flucht den Rio Grande überquert. Dann rissen ihr texanische
  Grenzschützer das Kind aus dem Arm. Amerika machte in jenen Wochen Ernst mit
  einer neuen Null-Toleranz-Politik., die vorsah, illegal eingewanderte Familien
  zu trennen. Jetzt geht es darum, das Chaos aufzuräumen, das dabei entstanden
  ist. Das Letzte, was Levis von Samir gehört hat, war, dass er dieses Heim in
  Phoenix, in das man ihn geflogen hatte, nicht mehr verlassen wollte.

  \flqq Überraschung\frqq, flötet die Wärterin und schiebt Levis in einen
  fensterlosen Raum. \flqq Samir ist nur noch kurz auf der Toilette.\frqq Levis
  sinkt auf einen Stuhl. Sie zittert. Dann steht er plötzlich in der Tür, an der
  Hand eines Sozialarbeiters, das Haar geschoren, das freche Zahnlückenlächeln
  eingefroren.

  \flqq Samir, mein Liebling\frqq, stammelt Levis, \flqq wie geht es dir?\frqq

  \flqq Ich weiß nicht, wer du bist.\frqq

  Levis geht einen Schritt auf Samir zu, er weicht zurück. Sie versucht es ein
  zweites Mal, er tritt nach ihr.

  \flqq Samir\frqq, sagt sie. \flqq Ich liebe dich!\frqq

  \flqq Du bist nicht meine Mutter.\frqq

  So erzählt es Levis, als sie ein paar Stunden nach diesem Wiedersehen
  übermüdet vor einem Teller Reis sitzt. Levis, die vor 26 Jahren in der
  honduranischen Stadt El Provernir geboren wurde, ist eine hübschen, rundliche
  Frau mit mandelförmigen Augen. Sie versucht, Worte für etwas zu finden, das
  ihr wie ein Albtraum vorkommt. Immer wieder ringt sie mit den Tränen, während
  Samir an ihrer Seite in die Fantasiewelt eines Handyspiels abtaucht.

  Fragt man ihn, wie es ihm geht, blickt er kurz auf und sagt: \flqq Ich bin aus
  Stahl.\frqq

  Die Sonne schimmert auf den Cafeteria-Tischen der Basilica-Herberge, die von
  der katholischen Kirche im Rio Grande Valley betrieben wird. Ein Gefängnisbus
  hat Levis und Samir in der Nacht hier abgesetzt, am südlichen Rand der USA,
  nicht weit von der Stelle, an der vor zwei Monaten ihr Floß anlegte. Sie sind
  jetzt frei, aber sie wissen nicht, wohin. Im Oktober, sagt Levis, beginne ihr
  Asylverfahren, bis dahin schiebe man sie immerhin nicht ab.

  Diese Herberge, in der normalerweise Pilgergruppen absteigen, ist jetzt eine
  Durchgangsstation für viele jender rund 3000 Familien, die Amerika Ende Juli
  nach und nach wieder zusammenführt. Es ist ein Ort der Menschlichkeit in einem
  Land, das seinen Kompass verloren hat.

  In der Lobby teilen Nonnen Kleiderspenden aus. Sie helfen, Verwandte ausfindig
  zu machen, und besorgen Bustickets. Sie verbinden Levis zum ersten Mal seit
  Wochen wieder mit ihrem Anwalt, der ihr am Telefon verspricht, einen
  Unterschlupf zu finden, an dem die Wunden heilen können, die sein Land ihr
  zugefügt hat.

  Die USA waren lange zeit ein Staat, dessen Grenzen offener waren als anderswo.

  \bigskip
  \noindent
  \enskip
  \parbox{.3\textwidth}
    {%
      \flushleft \bfseries
      Bis heute befinden sich noch immer 500 Kinder in
      der Obhut der Regierung.%
    }%
  \bigskip

  \noindent
  \flqq Gebt mir eure Müden, eure Armen/Eure geknechteten Massen, die sich
  danach sehen, frei zu atmen\frqq, so steht es am Fuß der Freiheitsstatue. Es
  ist das Fundament, das unverrückbar schien, seit die Vereinigten Staaten 1776
  durch die Nachfahren europäischer Einwanderer gegründet wurden.

  Der 45. Präsident ist nun dabei, eine Abrissbirne auf diesen Sockel
  loszulassen. In den Augen des ehemaligen Bauunternehmers Donald Trump sind
  Menschen wie Levis, die vor der Gewalt und der Armut in Mittelamerika fliehen,
  vor allem Kriminelle. Drogendealer nennt er sie, Vergewaltiger oder \flqq bad
  hombres\frqq. Trump glaubt, es seien zu viele, und um sie aufzuhalten,
  versprach er seinen Wählern den Bau einer Grenzmauer.

  Die Null-Toleranz-Politik, die Trumps Justizminister Jeff Sessions im April
  ausrief, war so etwas wie ein erster, unsichtbarer Wall; eine Maßnahme zur
  Abschreckung, die weniger kostet als ein Bauwerk aus Beton. Tausende Eltern
  wurden von Mitte Mai an in Haft genommene, ihre Kinder verteilte man über das
  Land. Manche fanden sich in Heimen wieder, andere kamen bei Pflegeeltern unter
  oder in leer stehenden Walmart-Supermärkten.
\end{multicols}

\vfill\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \Huge\copyright Spiegel, \\[1ex]
    \Large Nr. 36/1.9.2018
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]